# For what value of $c$, we have $\bar{\theta}$ is unbiased?

Tags: probability

> Given a population with the density function
>   $$f(x)=\frac{2(\theta-x)}{\theta^2}$$  for $0<x<\theta$, consider the estimator of $\theta$ of the form $\bar{\theta}=c\bar{x}$ where $c$ is constant.
>   For what value of $c$, do we have that $\bar{\theta}$ is unbiased?

**My attempt:**

By definition, a estimator is unbiased if $E[\bar{\theta}]=\theta$

But here i'm a little confused because i have a density function. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may get you started:
$$E[\bar\theta]=E[c\bar X]=cE[\bar X]=\frac{c}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE[X_i]$$
Then using the density function, you can find the expected value inside the sum.

Comment: Thanks for all!